# Coding problem : invalid byte sequence for "UTF8" encoding: 0xff

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have a CSV file, with 19 fields, some fields contain text in Arabic language.

The encoding of the file is UTF8:

[image]

I created a table in postgres with the same name of the fields of the file

The goal is to import the data from the CSV file to the table created.

```
CREATE TABLE Dubai_201606 (
    Case_Type_Arabic VARCHAR(100),
    Case_Type VARCHAR(100),
    Case_Number VARCHAR(20),
    Abbreviation VARCHAR(50),
    Notice_Date Date,
    Notifier VARCHAR(100),
    English VARCHAR(100),
    Notifier_N_Ref VARCHAR(50),
    Notifier_Licence_No int,
    Notifier_Company_No VARCHAR(50),
    Notifier_City VARCHAR(50),
    Party VARCHAR(100),
    Enlish_Party VARCHAR(100),
    Party_N_Ref VARCHAR(50),
    Party_Licence_No int,
    Party_Company_No VARCHAR(50),
    Party_City VARCHAR(50),
    Subject_Arabic TEXT,
    Subject_English TEXT 
)
```

Then I used Copy to import the file into the created table.

```
COPY Dubai_201606 FROM 'C:\Users\king-\OneDrive\Bureau\201606.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

After execution I had the following error

> ERROR: ERROR: sequence of bytes invalid for "UTF8" encoding: 0xff
> CONTEXT: COPY dubai_201606, line 1
>
> SQL state: 22021

Comment: Sounds like a [byte order mark](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (also called a BOM) is present in the file? We've run into this too. It is a marker that is not visible when viewed. May have to convert/save the file to [another encoding format](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/web-development/byte-order-mark/) to remove, or one could use hex edit to remove the BOM.

Comment: To me, it looks like the file is **not** in UTF8 encoding, which uses BOM `0xef 0xbb 0xbf`, but probably UTF-16 Little-Endian ('Unicode') which has an BOM of `0xff 0xfe`